# How to use sys.sm_db_index_physical_stats dynamic management view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to use sys.sm_db_index_physical_stats dynamic management view, eg. in order to show avg_page_space_used_in_percent (internal fragmentation) in SQL Server

Within SQL Server Management Studio 2014 in a virtual machine environment I created a table and inserted some data into the table. Afterwards when querying the **DMV** and **stored procedure**, eg. in order to return the **avg_page_space_used_in_percent** to show **internal fragmentation** an error occurred.

Steps I followed through:

1: I created a table as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(id INT NOT NULL,
filler1 CHAR(24),
filler2 CHAR(100));
```

2: Then, I put in the query as per below:

```
    SELECT index_type_desc, page_count, 
    record_count, avg_page_space_used_in_percent
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
        (DB_ID(N'tempdb'), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Test'), NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED');
    EXEC dbo.sp_spaceused @objname = N'dbo.Test', @updateusage = true;
```

The second command returned results successfully whereas the first command returned an error message:

> Msg 2573, severity 16, state 40 Could not find table or object ID
>   1301579675. Check system catalog.

How can I solve the issue mentioned above in regards to querying the dynamic management view?

Comment: What database did you create the table in? Was it actually tempdb?

Comment: And what is your current database context?

Comment: @MartinSmith That helped. It ran successfully after changing the query to reflect the actual database in which the table was created (and changing the database context). Issue resolved. Thank you.